# Есть ли название у такого подхода?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

```
static function setDataOne( data ){
    return new One( data );
}

static function setDataTwo( data ){
    return new Two( data );
}

class Test {
    var setData;

    function setFunction( fun ){
        this.setData = fun;
    }
}

var test = new Test( );
test.setData( setDataOne );
// test.setData( setDataTwo );
```

Есть ли "правильное" название у такого подхода?

**Обновление**

Подход состоит в том, чтобы менять поведение во время выполнения.
И это псевдо-код, да и разницы от названия языка нет.

А на живых примерах можно сопоставить методы сортировки, когда вместе с коллекцией, можно и сам метод сортировки передавать.
Но я соглашусь с ответом, который мне дали, лучше это дело как стратегия оформить.

Comment: @vas, опишите, в чем состоит подход, потому что я не понял

Comment: неплохо было бы еще указать язык. Не принципиально, но просто любопытно. 
А вообще подобного можно достичь более стандартными способами, в частности, полиморфизмом

Comment: Очень похоже на Dependency Injection.

Comment: Подход состоит в том, чтобы менять поведение во время выполнения.  
И это псевдо-код, да и разницы от названия языка нет.  

А на живых примерах, можно сопоставить методы сортировки, когда вместе с коллекцией, можно и сам метод сортировки передавать.  
Но я соглашусь с ответом, который мне дали, лучше это дело как стратегия оформить.

Comment: По-моему, это называется monkey patching. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Похоже на паттерн [Стратегия](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29) (потому что есть возможность в рантайме менять поведение класса путём изменения свойства, которое инкапсулирует логику поведения) или [Абстрактная фабрика](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29) (потому что есть сущности, реализующие единый интерфейс, занимающиеся созданием объектов).

Comment: @fori1ton, Спасибо!